# How can I run cucumber without any feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, hook, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm building an automation framework using Cucumber for BDD, JUnit and Selenium, we have a testrail instance in the cloud for test management and I implemented the testrail API for getting all the test cases from there, the problem is I'm not able to run these steps for getting the test cases because `cucumber` always validate first feature file exist.

I've tried with `@Before (Cucumber)`, `@BeforeClass (JUnit)` and the result is always the same:

No features found at [classpath:features]
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.019s

This is the main class starting the process:

```
 import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
 import cucumber.api.java.Before;
 import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.junit.AfterClass;
 import org.junit.BeforeClass;
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

 import static 
 com.mps.framework.support.support.Property.BROWSER_NAME;


 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(
    plugin = "json:target/cucumber.json",
    features = {"classpath:features"},
    glue = {"com.selenium.test.stepdefinitions", "com.mps.selenium.hook"},
    tags = {"not @ignore"})


 public class SeleniumCukes {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SeleniumCukes.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startSelenium() {
     LOG.info("### Starting Selenium " + 
     BROWSER_NAME.toString().toUpperCase() + " ###");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopSelenium() {
     LOG.info("### Stopping Selenium ###");
     }
 }
```

This is the hooks class:

```
 import com.mps.selenium.base.SeleniumBase;
 import cucumber.api.Scenario;
 import cucumber.api.java.After;
 import cucumber.api.java.Before;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

 import static com.mps.framework.support.hook.Hooks.hookAfter;
 import static com.mps.framework.support.hook.Hooks.hookBefore;

 public class Hooks {

   @Autowired
   private SeleniumBase seleniumBase;

   @After
   public void after() {
     hookAfter(seleniumBase.getDriver());
   }

   @Before
   public void before(Scenario scenario) {
     hookBefore(scenario);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i did not get your statement exactly. But can you please suggest, what exactly you are trying to achieve between runner and hooks.

Comment: Does testcase mean feature file? If u are using maven u can use `exec-maven-plugin` to run a simple Java program in a phase like `generate-test-resources`. This program will copy the feature files from testrail into the correct location for cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but it think what you are looking for is the annotation `@BeforeSuite` (use the import annotations.BeforeSuite)